# Juniper SRX220: How to access wan IP from lan?

Tags: linux, juniper

I have setup Juniper SRX220 and i have a small problem. I can access the system from lan subnet (192.168.0.1) but not vie wan (external ip) address. Is there a way to access internal machines from inside using external ip?
Example: I have ip 192.168.0.101 on my laptop and i have server with ip 192.168.0.50 and i have made a NAT rule, so port 80 is open from outside. Now i would like to browse xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 from lan and access the server just like i would access it using local ip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:
http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB24639

and here:
http://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/Cannot-access-websites-from-located-on-trust-zone-internally/m-p/45963/highlight/true#M5101